# Backup MySql Database?

Tags: php, mysql, backup

I have asked this question before but I haven't got an answer, so I'm rephrasing it.

I want to back up a db using either:

```
system("mysqldump -h DB_HOST -u DB_USER -p DB_PASS logindb > $location/$backup");
```

or:

```
sql="BACKUP my_db TO DISK my_backup_folder WITH FORMAT #";

if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {    
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    $error              = true;
    $message['error']   = true;
    $message['message'] = CANNOT_PREPARE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE;
    return json_encode($message);
}
```

But the first gives me an empty sql file and the second gives me nothing. Why is that, and if there is a way to find out what error occurred how would I do it ?

Also which method is better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some simpler code [here](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx)

Method 1:

```
$tableName  = 'mypet';
$backupFile = 'backup/mypet.sql';
$query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Method 2:

```
$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip > $backupFile";
system($command);
```

Comment: Already tried it, doesn't work as well, the first, the second I'll try it now.

Comment: I just tried the second method, the same error, that mysqldump is not recognized as an internal or external command. One question though, `$backupFile` should it have the location as well ? Because I have the location as well. For example the php file that executes it is in the same folder with the folder that I have the `$backupFile` point to.

Comment: You need to have location. However you cannot use mysqldump under windows. Do you have a linux server to try?

Comment: No, but any other operation works fine with XAAMP, why isn't this one working ? And this is a app in development so I won't be able to upload it on server because the code is a mess and I don't have the db there.

Comment: But then, why cannot I use this ? `$backup = 'backup_'.date('Y').'_'.date('m').'_'.date('d').'.sql';
  
  $sql = "BACKUP DATABASE logindb TO DISK = '$location/$backup' WITH FORMAT";
  
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  try{
   $stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();
  } catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   echo $e->getMessage();
  }` It tells me `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\assets\class\login\loginsys.php on line 527 that line being $stmt->execute();` , but if I don't use try it outputs an empty file.

Comment: execute needs some special permissions for the system since you use system applications in order to do your job. See if you have safe mode on in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Use try-catch, something like:

```
try{
    $stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Check log files for errors.

Comment: If I do that this is what I get: `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\assets\class\login\loginsys.php on line 527` that line being `$stmt->execute();`.

Comment: $this->connect->prepare($sql); should be changed in $stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql); otherwise the $stmt object doesn't exists

Answer (score 1):

The start post:

```
-p DB_PASS
```

And the right form:

```
-p[password]
```

I don't know why but the -p is agains the password, not equal to the other parameters. So be aware that you take over the examples well. I have seen different cases where this was the issue so take note of it.

Comment: OK. DB_PASS is a defined var, and it looks like this: `define('DB_PASS','mydbpass');`. But you're saying I must have `-p[DB_PASS]` instead `-p DB_PASS` ?

Comment: Yes, just tested it at a MAMP installation and with the " " space in between it does not work. It looks very not making any sense but it seems to be so.

Comment: I get this error in the log: `'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` and I execute this line: `system("mysqldump -hDB_HOST -uDB_USER -pDB_PASS logindb > $location/$backup");` from a PHP file on XAAMP.

Comment: First test with the absolute direct path to mysql, like: C:\mysql\bin\mysqldump If that works you might change your PATH variables. Considering you are on Windows since you did not mention that explicitly but XAAMP is mostly used on Windows.

Comment: Ok, then try to use the absolute path. It is most of the time easier to use some terminal, like CMD to test this kind of actions instead of running it directly from PHP. So open CMD, CD to the mysql bin folder and then try to run your command again to see if it is working at that point.

Comment: I still get that error: `'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. So it seems there is no way I can try this

Comment: Did you really move to the mysql bin folder? So your CMD terminal says you are in that folder? I suspect not otherwise that error is not very likely.

Comment: Where in the mysql folder, because there are lots of folders there.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is faster if you have exec permissions for php.

Check the SQL error log file.

/var/log/mysql.err - MySQL Error log file

/var/log/mysql.log - MySQL log file

For php you might put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` this to throw php errors if any.

Comment: I got some error `32767`. Where do I check the log, I'm testing on localhost ( XAAMP ) ?

Comment: And when I used @NarcisRadu's method I checked the log, I had to search for it in the xaamp folders, but this is what I got: `'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: execute this query to see `show variables like '%log_file%';`

Comment: OK, so I won't be able to use it ? Than should I use the second method ? And how exactly can I make it work ?

Comment: Try a linux environment and try the mysqldump method. However the first method from here should work http://stackoverflow.com/a/9063524/1168944 but I cannot say why is not working in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user have the permission to this database.

Below is the command to backup the mysql database

```
mysqldump -h [host_name] -u [username] -p[password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

Comment: This is the only one that actually worked, the second method didn't do anything. This one outputs an empty sql file.